# Maximum value vs. size of long and double in .NET

Tags: .net, types

It's known that in .NET size of both long and double is 8 bytes. However, double can store significantly larger number than long. How can it be, considering that double also needs to store data on digits after decimal point?

Shorter version of the question:

Math.Pow(2, 64) == long.MaxValue
Math.Pow(2, 64) <  double.MaxValue

Comment: double has less precision than decimal.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Range_of_floating-point_numbers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Short answer double only stores the most significant figure and not all the digits that could be in the number. e.g. if you have a double > max value of long it will not be storing any information for digits after the decimal point or any of the figure just to the left of the deciaml point.

For all details see [What every computer scientist should know about Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Explained in simple enough terms for anyone to understand :)

Comment: I initially used this text about year ago and found it really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Integer based types have whole number ranges from -2^(n-1)2 ... 2^(n-1)-1 (signed),
or 0 ... 2^n-1 (unsigned).

Fixed point variables are the same as integer based types, only with a constant factor (e.g. for 0.01: 0.01*(0...2^n-1)).

Floating point variables (float and double) in any language use a few bits for the exponent and the rest for the number before the exponent. They are less accurate (x+1 might equal x, is x is a very large number), but have a much larger range.

Comment: Btw, the "number before the exponent" is called mantissa or (better) significand, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand.

Answer (score 1):

double is floating point number. Whitch bassicaly meams that it as the number stored in double gets bigger it's beeing rouned, and the least significiant part is being dismissed.

For example in double when you have a number like 100 billion.
It might be exactly 100 000 000 000 or it might be  100 000 000 000,000 000 000 000 000 001

Comment: Though this is not wrong, it leaves out the main reason why double has a larger range than int or long, namely that it is a floating point number represented by a significand and an exponent.