# what type to use when long double is not enough?

Tags: c, biginteger, integer-overflow, integer-division

I'm writing a program that assigns prime numbers to each entry of a matrix and then I'll need to multiply some of them. 
The resulting number grows rapidly and I'm at a loss as to which type to use, as I'm getting "wrap-around" with long double :S

All the help is appreciated.

-Pickel

Comment: What langueage is your implementation on? You probably need to implement your own datatype for that. And there may be even some libraries around.

Comment: C. do you have one you recommend? I'm sort of a noob :D

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're required to implement your own arbitrary precision type, use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).  You'll want the [mpz_t](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Functions.html#Integer-Functions) (integer) type.  It's pretty well documented, and there are tutorials and StackOverflow questions you can look at.

Comment: thank you! that sounds complicated and I'm sort of a noob! I just need it for a tiny part of the project. would it be easier yo just create my own type?

Comment: I mean *to just create my own type

Comment: Probably not.  I would only consider making your own for educational value, not to save time.

Comment: +1 for using an existing library. Writing your own would take a lot of time - it's not difficult, I'd just call it messy.

Comment: I didn't mean make my own library. I just need a type and to be able to multiply and divide them

Answer (score 0):

You may have to implement your own big integer type. Check out:

[BigInt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just integers, there's `long long int` (at least in C/C++). If we're talking about doubles... Use a BigDecimal class.

Comment: I get the same problem with long long int. I'll check a BigDecimal one then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using "long double" as a type that it's a C or C++ assignment?

How big are your numbers?

[Maximum value vs. size of long and double in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582529/maximum-value-vs-size-of-long-and-double-in-net)

discusses some related stuff but may be beyond the scope of your assignment

Generally speaking you need an arbitrary precision library:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

But chances are that for purposes of an assignment you are not required to make things so complicated as to require the use of an APL

Comment: it's a C assignment. For instance, for a 6x6 matrix I have to multiply 7*29*79*89*97*101*113*127*131*137*139*149*151.

Answer (score 0):

if it's an integer, use the BigInteger class (in Java or .NET)

if it's a floating point, use [BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (only in java, .net still does not have a arbitrary precision floating number

if you're in C/C++, you have to create your own type

Answer (score 0):

If you refuse to use a library, and don't want to invent your own big types, why don't you keep track of extra factors of 2, or something like that.

```
while ( mybignum > BIGNUM_THRESH )
{
    twos++;
    mybignum /= 2; // use >>=1 if you use an integer type (you said you used double so therefore the /=)
}
```

then print out your answers as `mybignum * 2**twos`

Take a 64 bit int for twos and you're safe up to 2^2^64

Comment: I think I get what you mean. quick question though, if bignum is larger than the threshold it shows up negative so  mybignum> BIGNUM_THRESH = 0, right?

Comment: because of that "wrap-around" thing I mean

Comment: no that's totally not the point! floating point types work like the scientific notation, with base 2: like Y*2^X, 0<Y<1. The bits available are shared between X and Y. The number of bits N for X determines the maximum value to 2^2^N. My suggestion was just a quick hack to emulate this method, but with a (much) bigger N.

Comment: I've come up with an alternative solution but for argument's sake, I need only prime numbers so if each number is an integer Y multiplied by a power of 2, they wouldn't be primes :(